# I made a onClickListener for my recyclerView but just didn't work

Tags: android

this is in my main activity

```
    private void setUpGUI() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(new ItemAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(TodoItem item) {
            setUpSecondPopup(item);
            Log.d(TAG, "on item click");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(TodoItemsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + item.getId());

            getContentResolver().update(uri, item.toContentValues(), null, null);
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddItemPopup();
        }
    });
```

this is my adapter class

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private static final String TAG = "item adapter";
    private List<TodoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public ItemAdapter(ItemClickListener listener) {
        itemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public void addItem(TodoItem item) {
        if (!items.contains(item)) {
            items.add(item);
            Collections.sort(items);
            notifyItemInserted(items.indexOf(item));
        }
    }

    public void addItems(Collection<TodoItem> newItems) {

        for (TodoItem item : newItems) {
            if (!items.contains(item)) {
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public TodoItem getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // This listener listens for clicks to the viewholder. The viewholder passes back the position it is.
    private final ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "on click adapter");
            // Get the item that was clicked
            TodoItem item = items.get(position);


            // Set the completed state
            item.setCompleted(!item.isCompleted());

            //Update the UI
            notifyItemChanged(position);

            // Pass the item back the the itemclicklistener
            itemClickListener.onItemClicked(item);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, clickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TodoItem item = items.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item.getText());
        holder.subTextViewA.setText(item.getSubText());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isCompleted());

        //holder.backgroundLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ec48e418"));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    // The view holder listens to clicks on the
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // private RelativeLayout backgroundLayout;
        final TextView textView, subTextViewA;
        final CheckBox checkBox;
        final ClickListener clickListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener clickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            subTextViewA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTextViewA);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            //backgroundLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // Private listener fot the adapter to know about view clicks
    private interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }

    // Public listener to pass the item back to the activity
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(TodoItem item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
itemClickListener.onItemClicked(item);
```

Not setting click listener to any view of `RecyclerView` but calling `onItemClicked` method using `itemClickListener` object which will not happen on click of `RecyclerView`.

Set Click Listener in `onCreateViewHolder` method as:

```
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                            R.layout.todo_list_item, parent, false);
v.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);
return new ViewHolder(v, clickListener);
```

Comment: i got a error on this line v.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);
that setOnClickListener can not be applied to (itemAdapter.itemClickListenr

Comment: also i think this line itemView.setOnClickListener(this); finds the view and also in the onClick i have the getAdapterPosition() method what points to the position in the recyclerView